# How can I make the height of a Text View change according to the content in filling it with?

Tags: ios

My Text View is filled with content that I'm parsing with JSON. Each Text View has different content so the height of each one varies.

There's to ways to add a Text View, through the Storyboard or with code. Something like this:

```
UITextView *newsContent = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 238.0f, 290.0f, 120.0f)];
newsContent.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0];
newsContent.editable = NO;
newsContent.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Either way I have to determine the Text View height but since it changes every time, I'm looking for a way to make the Text View height change dynamically.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: TextView is a scrollable view, if your text goes beyond the height of the view itself, then it can be scrolled. `UIView` has a method called `sizeToFit` and usually all the subclasses of `UIView` overrides this method and size itself so the whole content can be fit within the view. You should give that method a try. Also, `UIView` has another method `- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size` which takes a size (you would want to give constant width but make the height very large) and it will return the size it thinks it can be best displayed with.

Comment: I dont want the text to shrink to fit the height, I want the height of the Text View to fit the content. Since the content varies from Cell to Cell I wouldnt be able to set a fixed height. Should I use something other than a text view? @chuthan20

Answer (score 0):

Use this

set High value for desiredHeight

```
CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(FIXED_WIDTH, desiredHeight);
CGSize requiredSize = [someText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0]
                           constrainedToSize:boundingSize
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGFloat requiredHeight = requiredSize.height;
```

But this is deprecated in iOS 6 you can use following for iOS 7

```
CGRect textRect = [someText boundingRectWithSize:boundingSize
                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0]}
                                 context:nil];
CGFloat requiredHeight = textRect.size.height;
```

requiredHeight is height to set for text view when textView width value is FIXED_WIDTH (which is constant), font is [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0] and text string is "someText"

Comment: you have to define it before using it CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(FIXED_WIDTH, desiredHeight);

Answer (score 0):

Implement the UITextView's delegate method to change the text view's height to its content size height every time its text changes. This is simplest if you are using autolayout and you have an outlet to the text view's height constraint:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    // [textView sizeToFit]; // seems no longer needed in iOS 7.1
    self.heightConstraint.constant = textView.contentSize.height;
}
```

But even if you are not using autolayout, the key is to change the text view's frame so that its height is its `contentSize.height`.